# Searching the date array

Tags: solr, content-search, custom-field

I have the following setup:

- I'm indexing Sitecore items (Employee) in Solr
- I have the computed field "checkins" of type stringArray set in the index

Checkins is list of datetime values I get from external service and I'm filling the computed field with them.

I extended the SearchResultItem with the property:

```
[IndexField("checkins")]
public IEnumerable<DateTime> Checkins { get; set; }
```

And when I query the index, property is filled with dates.

The question is now, how do I search on this property? I want to pick a date (dateFrom) and get all the Employees that have a checkin date after this date.

I tried this:

```
builder = builder.And(i => i.Checkins.Any(d => d >= request.DateFrom));
```

but I'm getting "Unsupported lambda in Any call." error.

Is there any way I can search in date array?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301106/query-lucene-index-against-ienumerable-field

In short, instead of using

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> Checkins
```

you can use

```
[IgnoreIndexFieldAttribute]
DateTime Checkins
```

And then you can search using

```
i.Checkins >= request.DateFrom
```

Checkins property will not show anything and is good only for searching. If you need to retrieve the list of dates, use another property as `IEnumerable<DateTime>` and use it only for retrieval.